# Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userJpaRepository'

Tags: java, spring

I have the following error when I try to acces into main page

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userJpaRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'net.codejava.spring.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userJpaRepository)}
```

In my UserController I have the following code

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private UserService employeeServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String employee() {
        this.employeeServiceImpl.listAlUsers();
        return "employee";
    }

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setEmployeeService(UserService employeeServiceImpl) {
        this.employeeServiceImpl = employeeServiceImpl;
    }

}
```

My UserService

```
public interface UserService {
    public abstract List<User> listAlUsers();
    public abstract User addUser(User user);
    public abstract int removeUser(int id);
    public abstract User updateUser(User user);
}
```

My UserServiceImpl

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userJpaRepository")
    private UserRepository userJpaRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> listAlUsers() {
        return userJpaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User addUser(User user) {
        return userJpaRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public int removeUser(int id) {
        userJpaRepository.delete(id);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public User updateUser(User user) {
        return userJpaRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

My JpaRepository

```
@Repository("userJpaRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Serializable> {

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My servlet-context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!--The <context:component-scan...> tag will be use to activate Spring MVC annotation scanning capability which allows to make use of annotations like @Controller and @RequestMapping etc.-->
    <!--Step 1 : HandlerMapping -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.loiane.controller" />

    <!--JPA Repository-->

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.loiane.repository.EmployeeJpaRepository"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--Step 3 : View Resolver-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!--Bundles-->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--Declaramos el interceptor para permitir el cambio de idioa en tiempo de ejecucion-->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!--Si el idioma no existe cargamos el en-->

    <bean id="localeResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieName" value="lang" />
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The root-context is empty.

I don't know where is the possible cause of error I try to find differents options , but If I use the DAO pattern I receive the same error , so I would to know which is to problem to try to solve it.

The configuration of the project is with xml but I think there is not important to solve this situation.

Regards !

Comment: XML is very important to solve this as the issue is because the repository is not getting autowired, so please post it. You are using annotations everywhere not sure why you wanted to use xml configuration.

Comment: Correct , I am using annotation for use this , I think that bean is not declared in xml for this reason I have the problem , I need to sleep ...hahaa

Comment: why you have `<bean id="userService" class="net.codejava.spring.service.impl.UserServiceImpl" />` if you are using `component-scan` in servlet-context.xml, are these service and repository in same project or in different project

Comment: Sorry , I don't have the userService bean in the file now and iI have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bean qualifier name on repository interface `@Repository("userJpaRepository")`. Qualifier names are useful if more than 1 class is implementing the common interface. It helps to resolve the specific bean, which is to be autowired to other bean's interface variable. Declaring it on an interface will defeat its purpose. Removing the qualifier name should work if no other class (other than spring created proxy bean whose name would be `userRepositoryImpl`) is implementing `UserRepository` interface.

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userJpaRepository;
```

And replace the Serializable with the Datatype of the ID column like Integer or Idclass.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {

}
```

Now to enable spring to scan for the interface that extent its predefined repository interfaces, add package to scan for in your spring context

```
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

   <jpa:repositories base-package="net.codejava.spring.repository"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with incorrect User import (instead of import a User entity that I've created manually - I've imported another User).

I've changed import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

[image]

to import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

[image]